# Infinite ajax scroll non automatic

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I put an infinite scroll plugin ajax, but works automatically when scrolling down. I want to change the auto-scroll with no automatic or with the "more".

The following is the code I used with masonry

```
jQuery.ias({
    container : &#39;#main&#39;,
    item: &#39;.post-outer&#39;,
    pagination: &#39;#blog-pager&#39;,
    next: &#39;#blog-pager-older-link a&#39;,
    loader: &#39;http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XIF8-dkyzkQ/UXC35axRdfI/AAAAAAAAGg0/Q7xRk-yFLP4/s1600/loader.gif&#39;,
    onLoadItems: function(items) {
        var $newElems = jQuery(items).show().css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
             $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
             jQuery(&#39;#main&#39;).masonry( &#39;appended&#39;, $newElems, true );
        });
        return true
    }    

});
```

link examples:  [page-elements.blogspot.com](http://page-elements.blogspot.com/)

Plugin infinite: [infinite-ajax-scroll](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll)

What should I add code to change in order to be non-automatic with the "more"?

I'm sorry if my language is less clear, thanks

the problem I'm done, I added the "**trigger: 'Load More'**"

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [triggerpagethreshold](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll#triggerpagethreshold) to 0 should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I solved It.

First you have to return "this" object from ias plugin.around line 85;

```
// initialize
        return init();
```

Then when you initialize ias plugin hold this variable in a global variable.

```
infiniteScroller = $.ias({
                            container : '.jscroll',
                            item : '.column',
                            pagination : '#content .navigation-js',
                            next : '.next-posts a',
                            loader : '<img src="https://raw.github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/images/loader.gif"/>',
                            triggerPageThreshold : 15,
                            history : false
                        });
```

And then where you are retrieving new data. After data loads to a page do this;

```
delete infiniteScroller;
                            infiniteScroller = $.ias({
                                container : '.jscroll',
                                item : '.column',
                                pagination : '#content .navigation-js',
                                next : '.next-posts a',
                                loader : '<img src="https://raw.github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll/master/dist/images/loader.gif"/>',
                                triggerPageThreshold : 15,
                                history : false
                            });
```

Hope this will be a help for you.